# SQL concatenate VARCHAR + VARBINARY with VARBINARY as hex

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

As the title suggests, is possible to concatenate the 2, with the result as VARCHAR and the VARBINARY data as hex?

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(50) = 'Hello World!' 
DECLARE @testvb VARBINARY(256)

SET @testvb = CAST(@test AS VARBINARY(256));

SELECT @test + @testvb --I don't want to cast this back to var char
```

The result should be: `Hello World!48656C6C6F20576F726C6421`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what i wanted to do

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(50) = 'Hello World!' 
DECLARE @testvb VARBINARY(256)

SET @testvb = CAST(@test AS VARBINARY(256));

SELECT @test + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@testvb,2);
GO
```

```
|(No column name)                    |
|:-----------------------------------|
|Hello World!48656C6C6F20576F726C6421|
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3ce9eee316eaa1abccc9f2f8440bf1ae)*

From [this Aaron Bertrand blog post](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-cast-vs-convert/), I found out that CAST [converts it back to original value](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=33e435b37d17846b27f28e8d6e316e39) whereas CONVERT has an option to keep the varbinary value:

```
SELECT @test + CAST(@testvb AS VARCHAR(MAX)) --converts back to Hello World!
SELECT @test + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@testvb,2) --keeps varbinary value
```

Comment: Hi Dave. Regarding "_CAST converts it back to original value whereas CONVERT does not._": that is a mischaracterization of what Aaron wrote and of what is going on with those two functions. It's not that they behave differently, the difference is that CONVERT allows for applying a "style" number, which in your example is the `2` as the third parameter in the `CONVERT` function. But CONVERT without any "style" number works the same as CAST, which is also the same as CONVERT with a style of `0`, because internally the `CAST` function _is_ the `CONVERT` function with a style of `0`.

Comment: As srutzky commented already, the *"CAST converts it back to original value whereas CONVERT does not."* part is just misunderstanding. Please edit/remove it. CAST and CONVERT do the same thing but the second is more flexible.